# PDF não gera todas as páginas com mPDF

Tags: php, mpdf

Tenho uma query que me retorna 8.093 registros tanto no banco de dados, como num sistema em PHP.
Estou fazendo um relatório utilizando mPDF que independente do filtro, ele só gera 6 páginas, o que na minha opinião, descarta a possibilidade de estar pegando algum dado nulo ou sem formatação.
Meu relatório possui cabeçalho e rodapé e está imprimindo 25 linhas por página.

```
    <?php 
    include 'MPDF57/mpdf.php'; 
 include 'conect/conecta.php';
 include 'banco-os.php';
 include 'logica-usuario.php';

 $OSid              = $_POST['OSid'];
 $dataHora          = $_POST['dataHora'];
 $NomeEquipamento   = $_POST['NomeEquipamento'];
 $NomeSetor         = $_POST['NomeSetor'];
 $motivoOs          = $_POST['motivoOs'];
 $TotalMaterial     = $_POST['TotalMaterial'];
 $NomeTipoOS        = $_POST['NomeTipoOS'];
 $status            = $_POST['status'];

 $topo = "

    <table border='1' class='table table-striped'  style='font-size: 12px;' >
        <tr>
            <td colspan='1' width='10%'><img src='imagens/logo-mini.png' class='img-responsive img-rounded'></td>
            <td colspan='7' width='90%' class='textCenter'>
                <p>            
                    Av. Lobo Júnior, 688 - Penha Circular - Rio de Janeiro - RJ<br>CEP: 21020-125
                    Telefones: 2156-0500<br > Assistência Técnica: 2156-0525 <br>
                    E-mail: <a href='mailto:riomed@riomed.com.br'>riomed@riomed.com.br</a> - Site: <a href='www.riomed.com.br'>www.riomed.com.br</a>                
                </p>
            </td>            
        </tr>        
    </table>";

 $corpo_pagina = "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='pt-br'>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Relatório - RioMed</title>
    <link href='css/bootstrap.css'  rel='stylesheet'>
    <style media='print'>
        body {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            }
    a {
        color: #000066;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    thead {
        vertical-align: bottom;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    tfoot {
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    th {
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 0.35em;
        padding-right: 0.35em;
        padding-top: 0.35em;
        padding-bottom: 0.35em;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    td {
        padding-left: 0.35em;
        padding-right: 0.35em;
        padding-top: 0.35em;
        padding-bottom: 0.35em;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    .textCenter{
        text-align: center;
        }

    img {
        margin: 0.2em;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    table.print-friendly tr td, table.print-friendly tr th {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
    </style>

</head>
<body>


    <table border='1' class='table table-striped'  style='font-size: 12px;'  >
        <thead> 
            <tr>
                <th width='6%'>COD OS</th>
                <th width='8%'>DATA</th>   
                <th>SETOR</th>  
                <th>EQUIPAMENTO</th>            

                <th width='12%'>CUSTO TOTAL</th>
                <th>TIPO OS</th>
                <th width='17%'>STATUS</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>";
            for($i = 0; $i < count($OSid); $i++){   
                $corpo_pagina .="
        <tr>
            <td>".$OSid[$i]."</td>
            <td>".$dataHora[$i]."</td>
            <td>".$NomeSetor[$i]."</td>    
            <td>".$NomeEquipamento[$i]."</td>            
            <td>".$TotalMaterial[$i]."</td>
            <td>".$NomeTipoOS[$i]."</td>
            <td>".$status[$i]."</td>
        </tr>
        ";                
        }

$corpo_pagina .= "</table>";

 $rodape = "

<table width='100%' style='vertical-align: bottom; font-family: serif; font-size: 8pt; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;'>

<tr>
        <td width='33%'><span style='font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;'>{DATE d/m/Y}</span></td>
        <td width='33%' align='center' style='font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;'>{PAGENO}/{nbpg}</td>
        <td width='33%' style='text-align: right; '>Rio Med</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

 ";

 date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    $date = date('d/m/Y H:i');

    $arquivo = $date." - Relatorio.pdf";

    $mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L',7,'MS Serif',7,7,27,13);    



    $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

    $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($topo,'0',true);

    $mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($rodape);

    $mpdf->AddPageByArray(array(

    'orientation' => 'L',

    'mgl' => '10',

    'mgr' => '10',

    'mgt' => '30',

    'mgb' => '20',

    'mgh' => '10',

    'mgf' => '10',

    ));


    $mpdf->writeHTML($corpo_pagina);

    $mpdf->Output($arquivo, 'I');
    exit();
```

Comment: chegou a verificar questões de memória e espaço em disco? Alguns processos podem ser interrompidos nessas situações. Quanto a mPDF, sempre preferi a TCPDF por estar disponível no packagist

Comment: Soube q o post tem limite. Não sei se dá para aumentar. Memória ram 8gb sem travamento e hd deve ter uns 800gb libres. i5.

Comment: agora que percebi que todos os dados vem por POST. É isso mesmo, existe uma diretiva chamada `post_max_size` que define o tamanho máximo de post em MB. Outra diretiva é `max_input_vars` que define quantas variáveis podem ser inseridas em uma query string, seja get ou post. Você deve alterá-las.

Comment: Outro ponto, no caso das memórias, o PC é uma coisa, a memória que o PHP utiliza é definido através de diretivas no `php.ini`, nesse caso, se as alterações acima não funcionarem, tente verificar sobre a memória em uso.

Comment: Não funcionou.
http://imgur.com/a/w7Zk9
Nada mudou.
Sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/EoeqO
Olha o resultado do meu relatorio.
Qualquer que seja a informação apresentada no relatório, sempre para no mesmo lugar.

Comment: quais foram as modificações que realizou? Reiniciou o apache conforme a alteração?

Comment: ; How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted
; max_input_vars = 1000
Para  
; How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted
max_input_vars = 1000
E essa  
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size=32M

Comment: Teu max_input_vars continua o mesmo, aumente para 10000 e teste.

Comment: Funcionou.
Mas eu tive que aumentar o timeout de 30 para 3000.
Só lá a resposta para que eu possa marcar.

Comment: Agora está indo só até 58 páginas.
Fiz uma consulta de 8.083 registros e isso deveria me retornar 323 páginas.
Não existe a necessidade de imprimir um relatório desse tamanho.
Depois eu vou fazer melhoria para passar só o parametro via post e gerar o relatório direto do banco de dados.
Obrigado.

Comment: Consegui.  
Coloquei o max_input_vars para 9000 e o post_max_size =128M
Obrigado.

Comment: Responda à sua própria pergunta. Fica melhor se as pessoas souberem que já solucionou o problema, e como solucionou o problema.

Comment: @GabrielHeming Fabor colocar a sua solução como resposta para finalizar essa questão. Resolvido ao aumentar a memória do post.

Comment: Bom dia, o que me ajudou foi aumentar o pcre.backtrack_limit = 100000 para 9000000.
No arquivo php.ini Valew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você está enviando vários dados através de um formulário utilizando o método de requisição POST, e conforme foi discutido nos comentários, você precisa configurar as seguintes diretivas no php.ini:

- `post_max_size`;
- `max_input_vars`;
- `max_execution_time`.

`post_max_size` indica o tamanho máximo que podem ser utilizados para dados enviados por POST. Caso passar desse tamanho, os dados excedentes são ignorados. Default 8M, aumente para 128.
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

`max_input_vars` indica a quantidade máxima de variáveis que podem ser enviadas do client para o servidor (seja em GET, POST ou COOKIES). Default 1000, aumente para 10000.
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars

No momento que você aumentou as diretivas `post_max_size` e `max_input_vars`, seu script começou a demorar mais tempo para ser executado (passou a possuir mais variáveis para o relatório). Dessa forma, seu script pode começar a apresentar timeout.

`max_execution_time` define o tempo máximo que um script PHP pode ser executado. Scripts como relatórios podem demorar mais que a consulta normal para uma página. Default 30, aumente o quanto for necessário. Se o tempo for variado, pode incluir 0 para ser tratado como "sem limite".
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time